# The Implementation of Users permissions SQL and VB.NET

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, interface, user-permissions

I am currently working on a project that is designed based on SQL and VB.NET. The idea as the following: there are different permissions for users. The administraotr grants each user specific permissions. The idea is illustrated as the following:

[image]

For example, user A can get the following permissions:

He is able to add new tender, modify existing tender, add new customer.

User B has the following permissions:

He is able to view existing tenders, add new employees, ... and so on.

The idea of how to implement it in SQL and VB.NET is:

Creating a new table called Permission with the following fields:

UserID (foreign key for the user ID), for each permission there will be a single field so there will be 12 field.

Now, in VB.NET there will be 12 buttons (i.e. Add new tender, Delete tender, ....). Each button will enabled and disabled based on the value of the field (if the field = 1, the button will be enabled).

Here is an example:

[image]

[image]

In this case, for this user the buttons with the red lines will be enabled and the rest will be disabled, based on his permissions.

It is obvious that this way is SILLY and is not professional to be implemented.

I need your recommendation of how to enhance it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to use an external authorization framework e.g. Microsoft's claims-based authorization or better yet, XACML - the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language.

When you use externalized authorization, all you need to write in your code (if at all) is:

*"Can I enabled button foo?"*. That's a question you send off to the external authorization engine. If you use an engine that "runs on XACML", then you get policy-based, attribute-based access control where you could easily define that:

- users that are assigned to a customer can add tenders for that customer

Check out open source solutions or vendor solutions such as [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com), the vendor I work for. Also check out available resources on XACML e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML or XACML videos on YouTube.

Comment: You can also use Microsoft's Authorization Manager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897401.aspx)